# External CSS won't change element style

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to change an elements class, but it doesn't seem to affect it.

The CSS file is loaded in `<head>`, but the class doesn't seem to have any effect.

My **HTML**:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">.col-sm-3</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">.col-sm-6</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">.col-sm-3</div>
```

and my **CSS**:

```
.col-sm-3 {
     background-color:black;
     height:500px;
}
```

Comment: it does work for me. Maybe try to set it up as a CodeSnippet for us

Comment: Maybe the CSS is loaded via HTTP and your site is using HTTPS

Answer (score 1):

this is because your bootstrap file is loading after the css file ,or try giving

```
.col-sm-3{
     background-color:black !important ;
     height:500px !important;
}
```

but giving `!important`is a bad idea since it overrides the bootstrap class.Hence try swapping the files make sure you css loads after the bootstrap file.

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid `!important`.

1. Include your custom css after bootstrap.
2. Use custom class to overwrite bootstrap style

HTML

```
<div class="col-sm-3 black-bg">.col-sm-4</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 black-bg">.col-sm-4</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 black-bg">.col-sm-4</div>
```

CSS

```
.col-sm-3.black-bg{
     background-color:black;
     height:500px;
}
```

Comment: I already included my bootstrap after my own css and still it wont load
but thanks for reply

Comment: @AdamŠulc Oh no! You need to include **your css** after boootsrap.

Answer (score 0):

do one thing, nest you css, write rules like this

```
html body .col-sm-3{
      background-color:black;
      height:500px;
}
```

it is the right way to override css

Comment: I have done this and it still wont load.. even my own css is included after bootstrap.